# How to show private members and methods in attached android source in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

For some reason when I open an attached android source code in the editor, it hides private members and methods. Although when I open the same source in a text editor (NotePad) the private members and methods are clearly there...

Without them the code is hard to understand at some places..

My questions are: why eclipse hides them? and how to make it show them (if possible)?

**Edit:** 
Now I realized thay are in the code but hidden in the outline (no filters on) and also F3 cannot be used to navigate to them..

So my new question is how to unhide them in the outline and allow F3 navigation?

Comment: if you are looking at the android dependencies in your project, you can only see the methods you are allowed to use and no more

Comment: You are correct, +1. Not only they are not shown in the outline, but also it is not possible to toggle a breakpoint for debug (You can break point the nearest protected or public method and step line by line into private methods, but this will not help if you need to define a conditional breakpoint there)

Comment: Same issue i am facing, while developing `smart gwt` application

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Eclipse hides methods from you. It is more likely that you have linked a wrong version of the sources where the private methods are just not there. So download the current ones and re-relink those.

Comment: I've maybe mistaken, because now I see the privates in the code, but not in the outline (no filter turned on). I also can't use F3 to navigate to the private methods/members.

Comment: Strange. Try to reset the perspective. Maybe it's something wrong with your eclipse. Then I would install a fresh copy.